# snmpget : Unknown user name

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, net-snmp, snmpd

I am trying to install `net-snmp` from scratch to make `snmpv3` to work on my computer.

I did install `net-snmp` and create the user, but when I want to make `snmpget` it reject me with `snmpget: Unknown user name`

---

- To install net-snmp I followed the [official guide](http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Net-Snmp_on_Ubuntu)
- I did install the packages `libperl-dev`, `snmp-mibs-downloader` and `snmp` too using `sudo apt-get install`
- Here is my `/usr/local/share/snmp` configuration where you can find the particular line `rouser neutg`

```html
###############################################################################
#
# EXAMPLE.conf:
#   An example configuration file for configuring the Net-SNMP agent ('snmpd')
#   See the 'snmpd.conf(5)' man page for details
#
#  Some entries are deliberately commented out, and will need to be explicitly activated
#
###############################################################################
#
#  AGENT BEHAVIOUR
#

#  Listen for connections from the local system only
# agentAddress  udp:127.0.0.1:161
#  Listen for connections on all interfaces (both IPv4 *and* IPv6)
agentAddress udp:161,udp6:[::1]:161



###############################################################################
#
#  SNMPv3 AUTHENTICATION
#
#  Note that these particular settings don't actually belong here.
#  They should be copied to the file /var/lib/snmp/snmpd.conf
#     and the passwords changed, before being uncommented in that file *only*.
#  Then restart the agent

#  createUser authOnlyUser  MD5 "remember to change this password"
#  createUser authPrivUser  SHA "remember to change this one too"  DES
#  createUser internalUser  MD5 "this is only ever used internally, but still change the password"

#  If you also change the usernames (which might be sensible),
#  then remember to update the other occurances in this example config file to match.



###############################################################################
#
#  ACCESS CONTROL
#

                                                 #  system + hrSystem groups only
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1

                                                 #  Full access from the local host
#rocommunity public  localhost
                                                 #  Default access to basic system info
 rocommunity public  default    -V systemonly
                                                 #  rocommunity6 is for IPv6
 rocommunity6 public  default   -V systemonly

                                                 #  Full access from an example network
                                                 #     Adjust this network address to match your local
                                                 #     settings, change the community string,
                                                 #     and check the 'agentAddress' setting above
#rocommunity secret  10.0.0.0/16

                                                 #  Full read-only access for SNMPv3
 rouser   authOnlyUser
                                                 #  Full write access for encrypted requests
                                                 #     Remember to activate the 'createUser' lines above
#rwuser   authPrivUser   priv

#  It's no longer typically necessary to use the full 'com2sec/group/access' configuration
#  r[ow]user and r[ow]community, together with suitable views, should cover most requirements



###############################################################################
#
#  SYSTEM INFORMATION
#

#  Note that setting these values here, results in the corresponding MIB objects being 'read-only'
#  See snmpd.conf(5) for more details
sysLocation    Sitting on the Dock of the Bay
sysContact     Me <me@example.org>
                                                 # Application + End-to-End layers
sysServices    72


#
#  Process Monitoring
#
                               # At least one  'mountd' process
proc  mountd
                               # No more than 4 'ntalkd' processes - 0 is OK
proc  ntalkd    4
                               # At least one 'sendmail' process, but no more than 10
proc  sendmail 10 1

#  Walk the UCD-SNMP-MIB::prTable to see the resulting output
#  Note that this table will be empty if there are no "proc" entries in the snmpd.conf file


#
#  Disk Monitoring
#
                               # 10MBs required on root disk, 5% free on /var, 10% free on all other disks
disk       /     10000
disk       /var  5%
includeAllDisks  10%

#  Walk the UCD-SNMP-MIB::dskTable to see the resulting output
#  Note that this table will be empty if there are no "disk" entries in the snmpd.conf file


#
#  System Load
#
                               # Unacceptable 1-, 5-, and 15-minute load averages
load   12 10 5

#  Walk the UCD-SNMP-MIB::laTable to see the resulting output
#  Note that this table *will* be populated, even without a "load" entry in the snmpd.conf file



###############################################################################
#
#  ACTIVE MONITORING
#

                                    #   send SNMPv1  traps
 trapsink     localhost public
                                    #   send SNMPv2c traps
#trap2sink    localhost public
                                    #   send SNMPv2c INFORMs
#informsink   localhost public

#  Note that you typically only want *one* of these three lines
#  Uncommenting two (or all three) will result in multiple copies of each notification.


#
#  Event MIB - automatically generate alerts
#
                                   # Remember to activate the 'createUser' lines above
iquerySecName   internalUser       
rouser          internalUser
                                   # generate traps on UCD error conditions
defaultMonitors          yes
                                   # generate traps on linkUp/Down
linkUpDownNotifications  yes



###############################################################################
#
#  EXTENDING THE AGENT
#

#
#  Arbitrary extension commands
#
 extend    test1   /bin/echo  Hello, world!
 extend-sh test2   echo Hello, world! ; echo Hi there ; exit 35
#extend-sh test3   /bin/sh /tmp/shtest

#  Note that this last entry requires the script '/tmp/shtest' to be created first,
#    containing the same three shell commands, before the line is uncommented

#  Walk the NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB tables (nsExtendConfigTable, nsExtendOutput1Table
#     and nsExtendOutput2Table) to see the resulting output

#  Note that the "extend" directive supercedes the previous "exec" and "sh" directives
#  However, walking the UCD-SNMP-MIB::extTable should still returns the same output,
#     as well as the fuller results in the above tables.


#
#  "Pass-through" MIB extension command
#
#pass .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.255  /bin/sh       PREFIX/local/passtest
#pass .1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.2.255  /usr/bin/perl PREFIX/local/passtest.pl

# Note that this requires one of the two 'passtest' scripts to be installed first,
#    before the appropriate line is uncommented.
# These scripts can be found in the 'local' directory of the source distribution,
#     and are not installed automatically.

#  Walk the NET-SNMP-PASS-MIB::netSnmpPassExamples subtree to see the resulting output


#
#  AgentX Sub-agents
#
                                           #  Run as an AgentX master agent
 master          agentx
                                           #  Listen for network connections (from localhost)
                                           #    rather than the default named socket /var/agentx/master
#agentXSocket    tcp:localhost:705

rouser neutg
```

- Here is my persistant configuration file `/var/net-snmp/snmpd.conf`

---

```
createUser neutg SHA "password" AES passphrase
```

---

The command I run is :

```
snmpget -u neutg -A password -a SHA -X 'passphrase' 
        -x AES -l authPriv localhost -v 3 1.3.6.1.2.1.1
```

[image]

---

I don't understand why it do not take in count my user. *(I did restart the snmpd after entering the user - multiple times!)*

[image]

---

The version of `net-snmp` I use :

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many research I've found what the problem is.

`snmpd` was not taking in count my configuration files. I saw it using the command :

```
snmpd -Dread_config -H 2>&1 | grep "Reading" | sort -u
```

Which tells you which configurations files are loaded by `snmpd`.

---

You can see it as well looking at the configuration file /var/lib/snmp/snmpd.conf. When snmpd handle your users it creates special lines in the file. It looks like :

```
usmUser 1 3 0x80001f888074336938f74f7c5a00000000 "neutg" "neutg" NULL .1.3.6.1.6.3.10.1.1.3 0xf965e4ab0f35eebb3f0e3b30\
6bc0797c025821c5 .1.3.6.1.6.3.10.1.2.4 0xe277044beccd9991d70144c4c8f4b672 0x
usmUser 1 3 0x80001f888074336938f74f7c5a00000000 "myuser" "myuser" NULL .1.3.6.1.6.3.10.1.1.2 0x2223c2d00758353b7c3076\
236be02152 .1.3.6.1.6.3.10.1.2.2 0x2223c2d00758353b7c3076236be02152 0x
setserialno 1424757026
```

So if you do not see any `usmUser` it's probably that your badly added your users.

---

### The soluce

```
 sudo /usr/local/sbin/snmpd -c /var/net-snmp/snmpd.conf -c /usr/local/share/snmp/snmpd.conf
```